# Does Umbraco Examine expose the underlying Lucene.Net API?

Tags: c#, umbraco, lucene.net, examine

Since Examine is a layer on top of Lucene.Net API, I am trying to find if it exposes any of the core Lucene.Net API or object reference like IndexReader so that I could perform some complex operations that is not possible with Examine. Is there any way, for instance, to get a reference to IndexReader object from the Examine SearchProvider or IndexProvider objects? I work with Sitecore as well and I know Sitecore's Search API exposes the underlying Lucene.Net objects which makes it a lot easier to perform additional complex queries.

In this case, what I am trying to do is, get IndexReader reference from my Examine instance, and pass it to another library [BoboBrowse](http://bobo.codeplex.com/) for facet queries. I do not want to create a separate IndexReader and manage path mappings and all that, if it is possible to retrieve from Examine. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it doesn't. You will have to spin up a new `IndexReader` I'm afraid.

At least all the paths to your indexes are defined in the Umbraco config files.

Comment: Thanks. Your are right, doesn't look possible with the current API. And the API is not well documented, had to hunt for a proper way to retrieve the paths: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093811/how-can-i-find-an-indexsets-path-in-examine